# How to compress the files in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my application I used html template and images for browser field and saved in the sdcard . Now I want to compress that html,image files and send to the PHP server.  How can I compress that files and send to server?  Provide me some samples that may help lot.

i tried this way... my code is

EDIT:

```java
private void zipthefile() {
    String out_path = "file:///SDCard/" + "newtemplate.zip";
    String in_path = "file:///SDCard/" + "newtemplate.html";
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    GZIPOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        FileConnection fileConnection = (FileConnection) Connector
                .open(in_path);//read the file from path
        if (fileConnection.exists()) {
            inputStream = fileConnection.openInputStream();
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        FileConnection path = (FileConnection) Connector
                .open(out_path,
                        Connector.READ_WRITE);//create the out put file path

        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.create();
        }
        os = new GZIPOutputStream(path.openOutputStream());// for create the gzip file

        int c;

        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            os.write(c);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.alert("" + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Dialog.alert("" + e.toString());
            }
        }
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Dialog.alert("" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this code working fine for single file but i want to compress all the file(more the one file)in the folder .

Comment: You can use `GZIPOutputStream` or `ZLibOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are not familiar with them, I can tell you that in Java the stream classes follow the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). These are meant to be piped to other streams to perform additional tasks. For instance, a `FileOutputStream` allows you to write bytes to a file, if you decorate it with a `BufferedOutputStream` then you get also buffering (big chunks of data are stored in RAM before being finally written to disc). Or if you decorate it with a `GZIPOutputStream` then you get also compression.

Example:

```java
//To read compressed file:
InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("full_compressed_file_path_here"));

//To write to a compressed file:
OutputStream os = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("full_compressed_file_path_here"));
```

This is a [good tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) covering basic I/O . Despite being written for JavaSE, you'll find it useful since most things work the same in BlackBerry.

In the API you have these classes available:
[`GZIPInputStream`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/compress/GZIPInputStream.html)
 
[`GZIPOutputStream`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/compress/GZIPOutputStream.html)
 
[`ZLibInputStream`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/compress/ZLibInputStream.html) 
[`ZLibOutputStream`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/compress/ZLibOutputStream.html)

If you need to convert between streams and byte array use [`IOUtilities`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/IOUtilities.html) class or [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

Comment: Hi Mister Smith thanks for your replay... i followed your way i got java.long.illegalArgumentException:Wrong API use javax.microedition.io.file... i edited my question please have a look

Comment: You are probably using `java.io.FileInputStream` and `java.io.FileOutputStream`. Try with `net.rim.device.api.io.FileInputStream` and `net.rim.device.api.io.FileOutputStream`.

Comment: BTW the created file is not a ZIP file. A ZIP file is compressed but is also a container that can contain several files and folders. You can of course name it as you wish.

Comment: Now i edit the question . i can compress single file but  i need to compress more then one file in a folder how can i achive this.. pls guide me

Comment: Then GZIP is no longer an option. Since there's no ZIP utility in the API, you'll have to use a third party library. Try with zipME (http://zipme.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Just my 5 cents. A couple of years ago I tried to use zipME, and unfortunatelly it has a bug - so that not every unzip tool can decompress the created by zipME archive. ZipME does not strictly follow the zip file structure format. Since in my case the unzip tool was out of our control (we distributed archives to other mobile diveces or even desktops), I ended up creating my own "zipper" that just uses zip format file structure, but actually applies 0 compression: https://github.com/vitkhudenko/blackberry_zip_packer In my case it was quite acceptable since 99% of data to zip were JPEG images.

Comment: If unzip tool is under your control and you can test it works with archives done by zipME, then you are lucky and can just use zipME.